# Hard divisibility problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, tag-removed

The statement of this problem is elementary... How about the proof ?
Let $p$ be an odd prime number. For every integer $a$ , define the number

$ S_{a}=\frac{a}{1}+\frac{a^{2}}{2}+....+\frac{a^{p-1}}{p-1} $.

Let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $ S_{3}+S_{4}-3S_{2}=\frac{m}{n} $. Prove that $p$ divides $m$.

Comment: I would like to see the proof. Voted to reopen.

Comment: $S_a(p) \equiv ((a-1)^p + 1 - a^p)/p \bmod p$  [proof: expand $(a-1)^p$
in a binomial series, subtract first and last term, divide by $p$, and
evaluate termwise].  So $S_3 + S_4 - 3S_2 \equiv (4 \cdot 2^p - 4 - 4^p)/p$.
But that's $-(2^p-2)^2/p$, which is a multiple of $p$, **QED**.


Comment: @Noam: Thank you! I was experimenting along similar lines, but did not get it. You saved me some frustration.

Comment: Five people voted to close this question, and not one could be bothered to indicate a reason, so I will: there was little reason to believe (even before Noam's comment) that there was any research angle here, and research is what this website is for. Now that we have Noam's answer, there is no reason at all to believe there's a research angle here, so I can't see any justification for reopening. 

Comment: Well, the punchline is related with the fact that 
a nontrivial homomorphism from $({\bf Z}/p^2{\bf Z}, \times)$
to $({\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}, +)$ is given by $a \mapsto (a^{p-1}-1)/p$.
(The formula for $S_a$ *looks* like a logarithm...)


Comment: @Gerry: If I find a question interesting and nontrivial, then I like to see the answer for it. All this is highly subjective, I know.

Comment: @Noam: Can you elaborate on your last comment? It sounds rather interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @GH: Observe what happens when you check that $a \mapsto (a^{p-1}-1)/p$
is a group homomorphism.  [While I'm at it, at the start of the proof
the formula for $S_a$ refines a familiar proof by induction of
Fermat's congruence $a^p \equiv a \bmod p$.]


Comment: @Noam: The way I check it does not bring in $S_a$: it is clear that the map is well-defined, so all we need is $(ab)^{p-1}-1\equiv (a^{p-1}-1)+(b^{p-1}-1)\pmod{p^2}$ for $(ab,p)=1$. This becomes $(a^{p-1}-1)(b^{p-1}-1)\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$, which is clear.

Comment: @GH: Right, the "punchline" is the special case $a=b=2$ of this argument
(with both sides multiplied by $4$).  It is true that $S_a$ no longer
appears by name by that point, but the formula $((a-1)^p + 1 - a^p)/p$
expresses $S_a$ as a linear combination of these "logarithms".
